# Iterar valores de un json y agregarlos a una tabla en react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código con la función *renderHeaderCells*: itero las keys del json y los agrego al header de la tabla y quiero hacer lo mismo con los values e insertar en la tabla los valores del archivo json para el body de la tabla. Estoy usando la función *renderResults* para iterar los valores e insertarlos en la tabla, sin embargo no sé qué está mal.

```
import React from "react";

const nomin = require("./nomina");

const Table = () => {
  const nominImport = nomin[0];

  function renderHeaderCells() {
    let headerCells = [];

    Object.keys(nominImport).map((x, i) => {
      headerCells.push(<td key={i.name}>{x}</td>);
      return headerCells;
    });
    return headerCells;
  }

  function renderResults() {
    let results = [];
    let res = Object.values(nominImport);
    res.map((x, i) => {
      if (res[i] !== undefined) {
        Object.values(res[i]).map(y => {
          results.push(<td>{y}</td>);
          return results;
        });
      }
      return results;
    });
    return results;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>{renderHeaderCells()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>{renderResults()}</tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
export default Table;
```

Esta es la estructura del archivo json desde donde obtengo las keys y los values:

```
[
    {
        "ccontrato": "19613210",
        "cnombre": "ACOSTA CABALLERO SIGILFREDO",
        "cconcepto": "DV240",
        "cactividad": "CORTE DE PALMA (1986-1991)",
        "ccantidad": 1.09326819307696,
        "ctotal": null,
        "cccosto": 200510,
        "ctotal2": null,
        "cdetalle": null,
        "cicontable": null,
        "cfecha": "06/16/2022",
        "creferencia": "912"
    },
    {
        "ccontrato": "19613210",
        "cnombre": "ACOSTA CABALLERO SIGILFREDO",
        "cconcepto": "DV240",
        "cactividad": "CORTE DE PALMA (1986-1991)",
        "ccantidad": 1.25524285840409,
        "ctotal": null,
        "cccosto": 200510,
        "ctotal2": null,
        "cdetalle": null,
        "cicontable": null,
        "cfecha": "06/17/2022",
        "creferencia": "882"
    }
]
```

Comment: Si usas `Object.entries(objeto)` te devuelve un array con un array de 2 valores por cada propiedad del json, el primero es el nombre de la propiedad y el segundo el valor. Así ya puedes hacer todo de una vez.

Comment: Gracias @Suso, ¿Cómo lo haría dentro del código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer la iteración directamente en el return.

```
    <React.Fragment>
        {data && data.length > 0
        ?<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                {Object.keys(data[0]).map(x => {
                    return <th>{x}</th>
                })}
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {data.map(x => {
                    return <tr>
                        {Object.values(x).map(y =>{
                            return <td>{y}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        : <></>}
    </React.Fragment>
```

Siempre y cuando data sea el array que pusiste al principio y tengan las mismas propiedades y en la misma posición.

```
    const data = [
    {
        "ccontrato": "19613210",
        "cnombre": "ACOSTA CABALLERO SIGILFREDO",
        "cconcepto": "DV240",
        "cactividad": "CORTE DE PALMA (1986-1991)",
        "ccantidad": 1.09326819307696,
        "ctotal": null,
        "cccosto": 200510,
        "ctotal2": null,
        "cdetalle": null,
        "cicontable": null,
        "cfecha": "06/16/2022",
        "creferencia": "912"
    },
    {
        "ccontrato": "19613210",
        "cnombre": "ACOSTA CABALLERO SIGILFREDO",
        "cconcepto": "DV240",
        "cactividad": "CORTE DE PALMA (1986-1991)",
        "ccantidad": 1.25524285840409,
        "ctotal": null,
        "cccosto": 200510,
        "ctotal2": null,
        "cdetalle": null,
        "cicontable": null,
        "cfecha": "06/17/2022",
        "creferencia": "882"
    }
]
```

Si quisieras controlar las propiedades de los objetos, tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
    const [mappedData, setMappedData] = useState({});
const data = [
    {
        "ccontrato": "19613210",
        "cnombre": "ACOSTA CABALLERO SIGILFREDO",
        "cconcepto": "DV240",
        "cactividad": "CORTE DE PALMA (1986-1991)",
        "ccantidad": 1.09326819307696,
        "ctotal": null,
        "cccosto": 200510,
        "ctotal2": null,
        "cdetalle": null,
        "cicontable": null,
        "cfecha": "06/16/2022",
        "creferencia": "912"
    },
    {
        "ccontrato": "19613210",
        "cnombre": "ACOSTA CABALLERO SIGILFREDO",
        "cconcepto": "DV2400",
        "cactividad": "CORTE DE PALMA (1986-1991)",
        "ccantidad": 1.25524285840409,
        "ctotal": null,
        "cccosto": 200510,
        "ctotal2": null,
        "cdetalle": null,
        "cicontable": null,
        "cfecha": "06/17/2022",
        "creferencia": "882"
    }
]

useEffect(()=>{
    getTableData();
},[])

function getTableData(){
    const headers = [];
    data.forEach(x =>{
        Object.keys(x).forEach(y =>{
            if(!headers.some(z => z === y)) headers.push(y);
        });
    });
    console.log(headers);
    setMappedData({...mappedData, headers});
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {mappedData && mappedData.headers?.length > 0
        ?<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                {mappedData.headers.map(x => {
                    return <th>{x}</th>
                })}
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {data.map(x => {
                    return <tr>
                        {mappedData.headers.map(y =>{
                            if(x[y]) return <td>{x[y]}</td>
                            else return <td></td> 
                        })}
                    </tr>
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        : <></>}
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: Excelente compañero @Suso, esto era lo que estaba buscando, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizo está función me itera solo un value, cómo quedaría para iterar todos los values del json:

```
function renderResults() {
     let results = [];
     let res = Object.values(nominImport);
          if (res !== undefined){
               res.map((x,index) =>{
                    results.push(<td key={index.name}>{x}</td>);
                    return results;
               });      
          return results;
          }
          return results;
}
```